# In what form should data be passed onto View?

Tags: python, model-view-controller, wxpython

Let's assume that I'm following the 'traditional' MVC pattern for desktop applications (a simple CRUD app) using wxPython.

The Model utilises the PeeWee ORM to interface with a Postgres DB. These objects are, obviously, custom classes and the view has no idea about them.

Let's define a Part class here:

```
class Part(BaseModel):
part_number = pw.CharField()
kind = pw.CharField()
description = pw.CharField()
unit = pw.CharField(db_column = 'unit')
```

The user clicks a button and a 'Edit Part' window pops up. This window needs to show a part's details.

The question is, does the model simply pass the above class' instance to the view and the view simply accesses the instance's properties? (myPart.part_number)

Or does it convert them to a more simpler form like a list or dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Controller?. Controllers are integral part of model-view-controller pattern. They act as glue between model and view. You need to create view model and pass that to the model through controller. Please see the example below.

Assume you have a viewmodel like this

```
public class ReportViewModel
{
   public string Name { set;get;}
}
```

and in your GET Action,

```
public ActionResult Report()
{
  return View(new ReportViewModel());
}
```

and your view must be strongly typed to ReportViewModel

```
@model ReportViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  Report NAme : @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Name)
  <input type="submit" value="Generate report" />
}
```

and in your HttpPost action method in your controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Report(ReportViewModel model)
{
  //check for model.Name property value now
  //to do : Return something
}
```

OR Simply, you can do this without the POCO classes (Viewmodels)

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
   <input type="text" name="reportName" />
   <input type="submit" />
}
```

and in your HttpPost action, use a parameter with same name as the textbox name.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Report(string reportName)
{
  //check for reportName parameter value now
  //to do : Return something
}
```

EDIT : As per the comment

If you want to post to another controller, you may use this overload of the BeginForm method.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Report","SomeOtherControllerName"))
{
   <input type="text" name="reportName" />
   <input type="submit" />
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue?. If answers provided by stack overflow members is useful to you please upvote and accept the anser. You can also downvote if the answer is incorrect or not useful.